# Redirecting to Front page when clicking on place order in virtuemart

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, virtuemart

I'm using virtuemart version 1.1.9 and joomla version 1.5.14. My problem is that when i click on add to cart then it is taking me to the place order and continue shopping. After that whenever i'm clicking on place order button then it is redirecting me to the frontpage. The link which shows me in the place order button is:-www.mysite.com.books.html?page=checkout.index&ssl_redirect=1. I'm not using ssl in my website. Even i have changed the configuration file of virtuemart and also i checked my logged file and it is showing me  PHP Warning:  stristr() [function.stristr]: Empty delimiter in /home/kiranpra/public_html/administrator/components/com_virtuemart/classes/ps_session.php on line 566. I think that it is just a warning not an error. I'm using inbuilt joomla sef not any other kinds of 3rd party extensions. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Update Joomla to 1.5.26 for security patches. Preferably 2.5 as 1.5 series has now reached EOL. However have you made sure the virtuemart plugin has SSL disabled (as well as the main joomla option being disabled)?

Comment: Yup my ssl is disabled in joomla config file and also in virtuemart also. I have a one page checkout extensions in my website so i just gave it a link for the checkout options

Answer (score 0):

There is something a little weird about the way that VirtueMart routes these requests.

The issue is a combination of VirtueMart's methods and your template which - if this is the same issue I've had in the past with a client's site - suppresses standard 'component' output on the frontpage.

I've no idea what template you are using, which template framework it is built on or which template provider built it, but you should go to the template manager and click through into your template's options and see if 'show component output on frontpage' is an option.

If so you should try it and see if that resolves the issue. Unfotunately it could mean you end up with other unwanted output when you navigate to your site's frontpage ordinarily.

I can't remember the specifics of how I resolved this in the end - probably with some code in the template to detect the frontpage (default page) together with the component being output, allowing the component output for virtuemart on the frontpage - but no other component.

Of course - you may be experiencing a totally different issue so your mileage may vary.